# Reading data from List<string>

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if it's possible to get all data from a List and put it in a single line, instead of printing everything from it in a new line.

So far I have tried using a `forEach` statement with `Console.WriteLine(data)` for each element

Comment: I am wondering if you have tried anything at all

Comment: it is. I hope you're not asking for some code? I

Comment: Could you show us what you did so far?

Comment: I tried a few things that I found online, such as foreach (string data in list){Console.WriteLine(data).

Answer (score 3):

Use [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) for that

```
List<string> a = {"a", "b", "c"}; 
var result = String.Join("," a.Where(..some condition if necessary..));
//result = "a,b,c";
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for  that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
// Identifiers used are:
var yourList = new List<string>();
string singleList = "";
string deliminator = " ";

foreach (string listItem in yourList) 
{
    singleLine += listItem + deliminator;
}
```

this will add all the elements of your list into a single line and a deliminator can be chosen to your liking.

Comment: Alright, thank you for  that.

Comment: No problem, there are more efficient ways but this is a good place to start